# WAR for Jersey REST Service fails deployment, but Guava is there

Tags: jersey, tomcat7, guava

I am unable to deploy the WAR of a Jersey REST service on a Tomcat7 installation.

Tomcat runs inside a Docker container that so far has worked flawlessly.

I copy the WAR in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps` and the initialisation fails complaining about a missing Guava class:

```
2016-09-25T13:29:55.444368315Z org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/simple02]]
. . . . .
2016-09-25T13:29:55.444460727Z Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
....
2016-09-25T13:29:55.444483641Z  at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:132)
```

Problem is: both **jersey-container-servlet.jar** (which contains JerseyServletContainerInitializer) and **jersey-guava-2.8.jar** (which contains Function) are in the same `lib` directory inside the WAR.

My hypothesis is that Tomcat is actually ignoring my `lib` directory altogether and running the `JerseyServletContainerInitializer` from some Jersey JAR of its own.

I don't feel like sticking a single Guava JAR in the definition of a generic Tomcat container and would prefer to operate from my `web.xml`.

Is this possible? I have tried several attempts without success.

The structure of the WAR is the following:

```
/WEB-INF
    /classes
        /com, etc. etc.
    /lib
        /javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
        /jersey-client.jar
        /jersey-common.jar
        /jersey-container-servlet.jar
        /jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
        /jersey-guava-2.8.jar
        /jersey-server.jar
    /web.xml
/META-INF
    /MANIFEST.MF
```

Comment: Are you calling guava in your code?

Comment: No, there is a dependency from Guava inside Jersey. A lot of questions on SO about this NoClassDefFoundError are from people who don't know about it, so they are told to put any Guava JAR (like jersey-guava-2.8.jar) inside the classpath and the problem is solved. In my case things ain't so simple.

Comment: I've had the exact same error using a Wildfly container. Now I am trying with a Jetty container, hoping that Jetty has already Guava in its sleeve.

Comment: i think there may be some errors in the web application directory structure. Can you show the folders in your WAR ? Btw the servers should be able to load all the files under web-inf/classes and web-inf/lib.

Comment: Edited the question with details about the content.

Comment: @Muzietto okay. jersey-guava-2.8 is guava repackaged as jersey internal dependency , but only added as internal dependency after jersey 2.6.x version. The version jersey-container-servlet.jar that you have is before 2.6.x when jersey has dependency on Guava. So, the fix would be to use the latest jersey-container-servlet.jar and for all other dependencies or atleast the version after 2.6.x. As a matter of fact you may look into using maven for dependency management. Hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: Maven is no option in this case, but you are correct. It's Jersey 2.2. How could you tell?!? Thank you, please  put this as an answer. Otherwise I'll do it myself.

Comment: I just looked at the error com/google/common/base/Function which is guava package and internal dependency package structure is jersey/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey-guava-2.8 is guava repackaged as jersey internal dependency , but only added as internal dependency after jersey 2.6.x version. The version jersey-container-servlet.jar that you have is before 2.6.x when jersey has dependency on Guava. So, the fix would be to use the latest jersey-container-servlet.jar and for all other dependencies or atleast the version after 2.6.x.